What is the relative polarization between the two photons created during matter-antimatter annihilation?
During matter-antimatter annihilation two photons are created. What is their relative polarization?  Are they both linearly polarized in the same orientation? Linearly polarized perpendicular to one another? Are they circularly polarized: left-handed/right-handed? (if so, which photon is which?) If the spins of the two particles are parallel do you get a different final polarization state than if they are antiparallel? Is there any consistent polarization at all?

they will be polarised in such a way as to conserve angular momentum.

Polarization versus photon spin. Do you fully understand $\pi^0\to \gamma \gamma$ ?

Review the counterintuitive clash of particle physics versus optical conventions, though!

Links.

are we talking ortho-positronium, or para-positronium? The former decays to $3\gamma$.

JEB, I didn't mention positronium at all. For simplicity's sake I was picturing a particle and its antiparticle (ie. electron/positron) on a direct, linear collision course. As I understand it two photons would result.
The particle physics vs optical conventions point is a good one. My classical physics understanding is stronger, which colours the terminology.
naturallyInconsistent, there are any number of final states which conserve angular momentum. Which, if any, predominate?

For an S wave collision, the back to back photons will have both positive or both negative helicity, thus both the same circular polarization.

That's perfect. Thanks!

As an aside, that seems weirdly imbalanced. Wouldn't the angular momentum of the system change if the two photons had the same polarization? Is it a consequence of the spin states of the original particles?

The photons are back to back, so their identical helicities amount to spins opposing each other, adding up to 0; now coordinate the circular polarizations to get linear ones...
